# Congruences for power-sum of divisors

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory

If $\sigma_k(n)=\sum_{d\vert n} d^k$, denote
$$F_1(q)=\sum_{n\geq1}\sigma_1(n)\,q^n \qquad \text{and} \qquad 
F_3(q)=\sum_{n\geq1}n\cdot\sigma_2(n)\,q^n.$$

> **QUESTION.** Assume the prime $p$ is either $2, 3$ or $5$. Is it true that
> $F_1(q)-F_3(q)\equiv F_1(q^p) \pmod p$? Are there other primes for which such a congruence holds?

**Convention.** The congruence should be interpreted coefficient-wise.

**Postscript.** Sorry, there was a typo in the definition of $F_3(q)$. Please read as
$$F_3(q)=\sum_{n\geq1}n\cdot\sigma_{\mathbf{{\color{red}3}}}(n)\,q^n.$$

Comment: To confirm, can I interpret this as saying the following two statements:
$$p\nmid n: \sum_{d|n} d-nd^2 \equiv 0 \pmod p$$
$$p|n: \sum_{d|n} d-nd^2 \equiv \sum_{d| \frac{n}{p}} d \pmod p$$

The second statement follows immediately since $n \equiv 0 \pmod p$, and the divisors $d$ in the left sum that have a factor of $p$ also vanish. Thus we only need to check the first statement.

It's straightforward to check
$$p\nmid n: \sum_{d|n} d-nd^2 \equiv 0 \pmod p$$
for $p=2$. Since these $n$ are odd, we have that $d(1-nd)$ has at least one of $d$ or $1-nd$ even.

Comment: Finally, the statements above are not true for $(n,p) = (4,3)$ and $(n,p) = (4,5)$, so the statement is only true for $p=2$ of the three numbers considered. Please let me know if I'm misinterpreting anything or making any mistakes.

Comment: Additionally, $(n,p) = (3,p)$ breaks the first statement for all remaining $p$ except $13$, for which $(n,p) = (4,13)$ breaks the first statement. Thus the statement is only true for $p=2$.

Comment: I made silly mistake in the definition of $F_3(q)$, it should be $n\sigma_3(n)$ not $n\sigma_2(n)$. Then, the claims are correct.

Comment: Thanks, I should have guessed!

Comment: Quick summary for myself of checking congruences to zero for $p \nmid n$. 
$p=2$ follows from top comment.

Otherwise, group the terms coming from $d$ and $n/d$ as $$(d - nd^3) + (n/d-n (n/d)^3) = \frac{1}{d^3} (d^2+n)(d^2-nd^4+n^2d^2-n^3).$$

$d^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ gives $$\frac{1}{d^3} (d^2+n)(d^2-nd^4+n^2d^2-n^3) \equiv d(1+n)(1-n+n^2-n^3) \equiv d(1+n)(1-n)(1+n^2) \pmod 3.$$ This vanishes.

Similarly, $d^2$ is congruent to $1$ or $4$ mod $5$. If it's congruent to $1$, we get $d(1+n)(1-n)(1+n^2) \pmod 5$. If cong. to $4$, we get $d(4+n)(4-n)(1+n^2) \pmod 5$. These both vanish.

Comment: The above confirms for $p=2,3,5$. We can rule out $F_1(q)-F_3(q)\equiv F_1(q^p) \pmod p$ for all other primes by noting that the term $n=2$ on the left hand side is congruent to $-15$, which means it is not congruent to $0$ mod $p$ for $p>5$.

Comment: I enjoyed the problem! May I ask how you noticed this? Does it have any fun implications?

Comment: It is part of an involved project where congruences are some added benefits. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote an answer in the comment section, so I'll rewrite it here.

---

The claim of

$$F_1(q)-F_3(q)\equiv F_1(q^p) \pmod p$$

is equivalent to the following two cases

$$p\nmid n: \sum_{d|n} d-nd^3 \equiv 0 \pmod p$$
$$p|n: \sum_{d|n} d-nd^3 \equiv \sum_{d| \frac{n}{p}} d \pmod p$$

The second case is trivial, because if $p|n$, we have

$$\begin{split} \sum_{d|n} d-nd^3 & \equiv \sum_{d|n} d \pmod p \\ &\equiv \sum_{d|\frac{n}{p}} d \pmod p\end{split}$$

---

Thus we only need to check
$$p\nmid n: \sum_{d|n} d-nd^3 \equiv 0 \pmod p$$

For $p=2$, this is immediate as it holds for each term in the sum individually. That is, we necessarily have $n \equiv 1 \pmod 2$, and $d-nd^3 \equiv d-d^3 \equiv d(1-d)(1+d) \equiv 0 \pmod 2$.

---

For $p=3$ and $p=5$, it is worthwhile to write

$$\sum_{d|n} d-nd^3 = \sum_{d|n\text{ and } d<\sqrt{n}} (d-nd^3)+\left(\frac{n}{d}-n\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)^3\right)$$

My claim is that each term in the sum on the right is congruent to $0$ mod $3$ and $5$.

This follows from

$$(d-nd^3)+\left(\frac{n}{d}-n\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)^3\right) = \frac{1}{d^3}(d^2+n)(d^2-nd^4+n^2d^2-n^3)$$

We can now proceed by cases, remembering that $p \nmid n$ and hence $p \nmid d$.

---

For $p=3$, first note that $d^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$.

Then we enjoy

$$\begin{split} \frac{1}{d^3}(d^2+n)(d^2-nd^4+n^2d^2-n^3) &\equiv d (1+n)(1-n+n^2-n^3) \pmod 3 \\ \equiv d(1+n)(1-n)(1+n^2) \pmod 3 \end{split}$$

Note that we have $n \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ or $n \equiv 2 \pmod 3$, and plugging those in gives congruence to $0$.

Thus we have confirmed the $p=3$ case.

---

For $p=5$, first note that $d^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$ or $d^2 \equiv 4 \pmod 5$.

In the first case,

$$\begin{split} \frac{1}{d^3}(d^2+n)(d^2-nd^4+n^2d^2-n^3) & \equiv d(1+n)(1-n)(1+n^2) \pmod 5 \end{split}$$

In the second case,

$$\begin{split} \frac{1}{d^3}(d^2+n)(d^2-nd^4+n^2d^2-n^3) & \equiv d(4+n)(4-n)(1+n^2) \pmod 5 \end{split}$$

It's straightforward to check that $n \equiv 1,2,3,4 \pmod 5$ plugged into the above will vanish.

Thus we have confirmed the $p=5$ case.

---

We can rule out the claim of $$F_1(q)-F_3(q)\equiv F_1(q^p) \pmod p$$ for all other $p$ by noting that for $n=2$,
$$\sum_{d|n} d-nd^3 \equiv -15 \pmod p$$

This is a problem for prime $p>5$, as then we have $p \nmid n$ but $\sum_{d|n} d-nd^3$ is not congruent to $0$.

(As an aside, note that this isn't a problem for $p=2$, since then $p|n$ and it's straightforward to check that it's congruent to $\sum_{d|\frac{n}{p}} d$, as needed. This isn't a problem for $p=3,5$, since then $p \nmid n$ and we clearly have congruence to $0$, as needed.)

---

EDIT: I realized that in proving the $p=3,5$ cases for $p \nmid n$ that there was an edge case I needed to check. I check this edge case here.

To prove the cases of $p=3,5$, I used

$$\sum_{d|n} d-nd^3 = \sum_{d|n\text{ and } d<\sqrt{n}} (d-nd^3)+\left(\frac{n}{d}-n\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)^3\right)$$

This works whenever $\sqrt{n}$ is not an integer. When $\sqrt{n}$ is an integer, it's a valid divisor, and in that case we'll have one more term

$$\sum_{d|n} d-nd^3 = \sqrt{n}-n(\sqrt{n})^3 + \sum_{d|n\text{ and } d<\sqrt{n}} (d-nd^3)+\left(\frac{n}{d}-n\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)^3\right)$$

So far, I showed that the rightmost sum is congruent to $0$ mod $3$ and $5$, so I only need to check this extra term. This extra term is

$$ \sqrt{n}-n(\sqrt{n})^3 = \sqrt{n}(1-n)(1+n)$$

For the case of $p=3$, $n \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, since $n$ is a square number not divisible by $3$. For the case of $p=5$, $n \equiv 1 \pmod 5$ or $n \equiv 4 \pmod 5$, since $n$ is a square number not divisible by $5$. Plugging these values in confirms congruence to $0$.